# Magento 2 add class to body via Layout Update XML

Tags: html, xml, magento, magento2

How I can add class to a body tag for CMS page via Layout Update XML.
I am trying different variants like this

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
  <attribute name="class" value="my-css-class"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code.

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="my-css-class"/>
</body>
```

Tested and working fine in 2.1.7.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution i've found is to add a class to the root container.
This element will be displayed immediately after the body tag.

I've used this code:

```
<referenceContainer name="root" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-class">
</referenceContainer>
```

For me worked in the Layout Update XML for CMS pages and categories.

Unfortunately is the only solution iv'e found similar to the old "addBodyClass".

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your css or js file like this on your xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <css src="Namespace_Module::css/styles.css"/>
    <script src="Namespace_Module::js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Namespace_Module::js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Class" name="Namespace_Module" template="Template.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Then on your module web folder (view/frontend/web), create js and css folders and place your files there.